# Django Rest Framework: serializer for two models that inherit from a common base abstract model

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

There is an abstract model that defines an *interface* for two child models. 
I've been asked to create an API endpoint that will return instances from those child models (including only the common fields defined thanks to the *interface* father class).

The problem raises when defining the `Serializer.Meta.model` attribute.

Anyway, code is always clearer:

***models.py***

```py
class Children(Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Daughter(Children):
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.xx

class Son(Children):
    def get_foo(self):
        return self.yy
```

***api/views.py***

```py
class ChildrenApiView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ChildrenSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        daughters = Daughter.objects.all()
        sons = Son.objects.all()
        return list(daughters) + list(sons)
```

***serializers.py***

```py
class ChildrenSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    foo = CharField(source="get_foo", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
      model = Children  # <========= HERE IS THE PROBLEM
      fields = ('foo',)
```

Some thoughts;

1. I know I'm not able to point out to the abstract model `Children` (wrote it for showing the inntention)
2. I tried to leave `ChildrenSerializer.Meta.model` empty
3. Seems that I can choose whichever `Daughter` or `Son` but not sure if that solution has any side-effect or is the way to go.
4. Tried to create `DaughterSerializer` & `SonSerializer` and use the method `get_serializer_class(self)` at the view, but wasn't able to make it run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probabaly not have a model serializer, and instead have a standard Serializer, with all the fields that you want to return in the view.

This will make it applicable for both Son and Daughter.

So the serializer would be something like:

```
class ChildrenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    foo = CharField(source="get_foo", read_only=True)
```